# javascript unpacking an object?

Tags: javascript

coming from clojure I need to write some javascript functions

Lets say I have a function that acts on some spec object.. I want to refer to the variables in spec in a local scope without having to write spec.container, spec.nrow, spec.ncol. It seems there is no native support for destructuring, is this correct? If so
how would I write an unpack (depth 1) function as below? - I don't really want to use eval in it either.

```
var spec = {container: {width: 900, height: 600}, nrow: 4, ncol: 5, vgap: "5px"}

function grid(spec) {
   // bad..
   var width = spec.container.width;
   var height = spec.container.height;
   var nrow = spec.nrow;
   etc...

   // I would prefer to write this, then have local access to nrow, width, height, etc
   unpack(spec);
   unpack(container);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Destructing assignment is in ECMAScript 6 draft and currently supported only in Firefox and Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with() { }` construct was designed for this, but it's widely considered a dangerous language element, as the rules for scope-conflict are not well defined.

I'd say either use the fully-qualified object reference, or live with the one-by-one assignment.

Comment: Also, *with* is not available in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: Good point. And ES5 = EcmaScript v5 (JavaScript's correct name) for those not up on that acronym.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want using the following:

```
var spec = {container: {width: 900, height: 600}, nrow: 4, ncol: 5, vgap: "5px"}

function grid(obj) {
    // I would prefer to write this, then have local access to nrow, width, height, etc
    unpack(obj, this);
    unpack(container, this);

    //do stuff here...
}

function unpack(obj, dest) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        dest[key] = obj[key];
    }
}
```

Here is a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Dsaaw/

Comment: You **must** use a *hasOwnProperty*.

Comment: Not must, may.  You *may* use `hasOwnProperty` if you want to exclude inherited properties from the unpacking step.  Depending upon the exact use-case, this may or may not be desired.  Similarly, you may also want to check the destination context to ensure that you are not overwriting anything that has been previously defined there.

Comment: well, it might be a good idea to kinda worry about it if `this` == `window` to know what you are setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [Coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), which has "native" destructuring assignment in that it compiles to the equivalent JavaScript. I don't think there's a really elegant solution that's strictly pure JS, though. The CS would look like this

```
{ nrow, container: { width, height } } = spec
```

The JavaScript that this produces when compiled will be:

```
var height, nrow, width, _ref;
nrow = spec.nrow, _ref = spec.container, width = _ref.width, height = _ref.height;
```

**aroth**'s solution is neat, and I was going to suggest it, actually, but I think you run a risk of scope issues. Worth a try, though.

Comment: Thanks, I would look into coffeescript -  however i'm going to target google closures compiler which means pure js

Comment: @ChrisR Why not compile to JS and then run through Closure Compiler?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend `this` with your other object, then aroth's solution is pretty okay, especially with RobG's comment, but just make sure you know what object you are extending. For deeply nested function (whose parent is not `window`) you would have to say `this.width` rather than `spec.width` so that doesn't help you much, in terms of typing. Or you could not pass in `this` and just make global variables on `window` (which is essentially what is going on), which may demonstrate why this approach could be dangerous-ish.

if you want locally scoped variables to the function, then I think you pretty much have to use an eval.

```
function decomp(obj) {
    var result = []
    for(var i in obj) {
        switch(typeof(obj[i])) {
            case "number":
            case "boolean":
            case "string":
            result.push("var "+i+"="+obj[i].constructor.name+"(\""+obj[i].valueOf()+"\");")
        }
    }

    return result.join('');
}

var someObject = {
    worker: function(obj) {
        eval(decomp(obj));
        eval(decomp(obj.container));

        alert(width);
    }
}

var spec = {container: {width: 900, height: 600}, nrow: 4, ncol: 5, vgap: "5px", test: true }

someObject.worker(spec)
```

Play around with it here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrdLg/3/)

I know that you said you would prefer not to use `eval()` but I can't think of any other way to really do what you want. Its between `eval()`, extending `this` (which may or may not be `window`), or writing a js pre-processor that unrolls it for you.